# Kubernetes Ingress same with with master-slave architecture

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, distributed-system, ingress-controller

I am trying to create a service which follows vertical replication-

[image]

In this architecture, requestes goes to the master node. For that I can use a kubernetes ingress.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: / 
        backend:
          serviceName: master-node
          servicePort: http
```

Now my requirement is if master is down, then request should go to the slave node.
I can achieve that by creating three paths `/master`, `/slave-1`, `/slave-2`. But the constraint is that **the path of request must remain same**. So, the path must always be `/`

How can I create a ingress in such a way that if `master-node` is down, then all requests should forward to the `slave-1-node`?

I want to achieve something like below-

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: / 
        priority: 1
        backend:
          serviceName: master-node
          servicePort: http
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: / 
        priority: 2
        backend:
          serviceName: slave-1-node
          servicePort: http
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: / 
        priority: 3
        backend:
          serviceName: slave-2-node
          servicePort: http
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this using *just* an ingress resource, but it would be very easy if you were to deploy an haproxy pod in front of your services, so that your architecture looks like this:

[image]

Using an haproxy configuration like this, you would get the behavior you want:

```
global
    log         stdout format raw local0
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy

defaults
    mode    http
    log global
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    option  http-server-close
    option  forwardfor  except 127.0.0.0/8
    option  redispatch
    retries 3
    timeout connect     10s
    timeout client      1m
    timeout server      1m

frontend  example_fe
    bind 0.0.0.0:8080
    default_backend example_be

backend example_be
    option httpchk GET /healthz

    server alpha example-alpha:80 check
    server beta example-beta:80 check backup
    server gamma example-gamma:80 check backup
```

This will send all requests to `alpha` as long it is running. If `alpha` is offline, requests will go to `beta`, and if `beta` is not running, requests will go to `gamma`. I found [this article](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/failover-and-worst-case-management-with-haproxy/) useful when looking for information about how to set this up.

You create a Deployment that runs haproxy:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: haproxy
  name: haproxy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: haproxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: haproxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: docker.io/haproxy:latest
        name: haproxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/local/etc/haproxy
          name: haproxy-config
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          name: haproxy-config-ddc898c5f5
        name: haproxy-config
```

A Service pointing at that Deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: haproxy
  name: haproxy
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    app: haproxy
```

And then point the Ingress at that Service:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: haproxy
            port:
              name: http
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

I've put together a complete configuration [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-73996233) if you want to try this out.